# SQLiteException - SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Tags: c#, sqlite

When querying data from SQLite, it says:

**SQLite error Insufficient parameters supplied to the command**

I think there is either a bug, or the error message is misleading.
Because I only have one parameter and I am providing it, so I cannot understand where is the problem.

Here is my code:

```c#
public List<T> Read(string sql, List<SQLiteParameter> addParametera = null, params string[] properties)
{
    var data = new DataTable();

    var command = new SQLiteCommand(Connection);
    command.CommandText = sql;
    addParametera?.ForEach(p => command.Parameters.Add(p));
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // <- ERROR
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        data.Load(reader);
    }
    reader.Close();

    var maps = Maps.ByProperties(properties).ToList();
    var results = data.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => New(r, maps)).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

an here the command object:
[image: command object]

Comment: The parameter name of the parameter object is NULL, I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, You are great!

Comment: You're welcome. I added it as an answer below, please accept it, so this question can be wrapped up.

Comment: The mistake was, I used a wrong constructor [new SQLiteParameter(type, parameterName) { Value = parameterValue}] instead of **new SQLiteParameter(type, parameterValue) {ParameterName = parameterName}** in an other part of code.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter name of the parameter object is NULL, I'm guessing that's the problem